# PyTorch NotImplementedError in forward function

Tags: python, pytorch

I am receiving a forward_unimplemented raise NotImplementedError issue for forward function in the Middle_RN50 class. Usually this error is attributed to indentation or small misspelling which is neither. Any suggestions on how to resolve. Thanks in advance.

```
     class Middle_RN50(torch.nn.Module):
         def __init__(self, rn50):
             super(Middle_RN50, self).__init__()
             self.start = torch.nn.Sequential(rn50.conv1, rn50.relu, rn50.maxpool,rn50.layer1, rn50.layer2,rn50.layer3, rn50.layer4)


         def forward(self, x):
             x = self.start(x)
             return x

    class End_RN50(torch.nn.Module):
         def __init__(self, rn50):
             super(End_RN50, self).__init__()
             self.avgpool = rn50.avgpool
             self.fc = rn50.fc

         def forward(self, x):
             x = self.avgpool(x)
             x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
             x = self.fc(x)
             return x


    def calibrate_end(model,cal_loader):
    
        rn50_middle = Middle_RN50(model)
        rn50_middle.eval()
        rn50_end = End_RN50(model)
        rn50_end.eval()

        for i, (images, target) in enumerate(cal_loader):
            temp = rn50_middle(images)
            output = rn50_end(temp)


   
    model = models.__dict__['resnet50'](pretrained=False)

    state_dict = torch.load('resnet50-19c8e357.pth', map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    model.eval()

    normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                       std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

    cal_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.ImageFolder("calibration_dataset/", 
    transforms.Compose([
                transforms.Resize(256),
                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                normalize,
            ])),

            batch_size=1, shuffle=False,
            num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)



    calibrate_end(model, cal_loader)
```

```
/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision-0.14.0a0+59c4de9-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/torchvision/io/image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: 
  warn(f"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}")

/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision-0.14.0a0+59c4de9-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/torchvision/models/_utils.py:208: UserWarning: The parameter 'pretrained' is deprecated since 0.13 and will be removed in 0.15, please use 'weights' instead.
  warnings.warn(
/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision-0.14.0a0+59c4de9-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/torchvision/models/_utils.py:223: UserWarning: Arguments other than a weight enum or `None` for 'weights' are deprecated since 0.13 and will be removed in 0.15. The current behavior is equivalent to passing `weights=None`.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sdp/backup/resnet50/pytorch-cpu/calibration/int8_quantization_model_partition/int8_separate.py", line 132, in <module>
    calibrate_end(model, cal_loader)
  File "/home/sdp/backup/resnet50/pytorch-cpu/calibration/int8_quantization_model_partition/int8_separate.py", line 96, in calibrate_end
    temp = rn50_middle(images)
  File "/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sdp/backup/resnet50/pytorch-cpu/calibration/int8_quantization_model_partition/int8_separate.py", line 41, in forward
    x = self.start(x)
  File "/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 141, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sdp/anaconda3/envs/ipex-calibration-int8_revised/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 201, in _forward_unimplemented
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error backtrace?

Comment: Thank you, I have provided stacktrace